# Pharo Seaside - How to update a Database entry after editing a tag in html

Tags: jquery, html, postgresql, pharo, seaside

I am a begginner in Seaside.

I have a table (like a spreadsheet) made using html in Pharo 4.0 Seaside, that takes data from a PostgreSQL DB using the Garage driver for Seaside.

I put `contenteditable=true` to the tableData and I can modify it, but it does not update the entry in the database.

I do not want to use a form that gets the data and then runs a query once I click submit, I just want to modify the spreadsheet cell (the html tabledata tag) and then when I press enter (or I just take the mouse off the cell) I want to run a Query that updates the database.

I tried using jQuery and Ajax but I can't make it work. I am not able to get the data that I entered and the data that describes the cell so I can run a Query.

```
html tableData 
attributeAt: 'contenteditable' put: 'true'; 
onClick: (html jQuery this addClass:'clicked'); 
onBlur:(self insertOrUpdateEntryWithCode: ((html jQuery this)html) withName: name forDay: day month:month year:year); 
with: value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then try this:

```
renderContentOn: html
  html
    table: [ 1 to: 10 do: [ :rowIndex | 
       html tableRow: [ 1 to: 5 do:
         [ :colIndex | self renderCellAtRow: rowIndex column: colIndex on: html ] ] ] ]
```

```
renderCellAtRow: rowIndex column: colIndex on: html
    ^ html tableData
        attributeAt: 'contenteditable' put: 'true';
        id: (self cellIdRow: rowIndex col: colIndex);
        onBlur:
            (html jQuery ajax
                callback: [ :v | self atRow: rowIndex column: colIndex put: v ]
                    value: html jQuery this html;
                onComplete:
                    ((html jQuery id: (self cellIdRow: rowIndex col: colIndex)) load
                        html: [ :h | h render: (self atRow: rowIndex column: colIndex) ]));
        with: (self atRow: rowIndex column: colIndex)
```

```
cellIdRow: rowIndex col: colIndex
    ^ 'r<1p>c<2p>' expandMacrosWith: rowIndex with: colIndex
```

You'll have to sanitize the content of html submitted, since a newline is going to be converted to `<br>`, which if submitted again will be converted to `&lt;br&gt;`, etc.

`atRow:column` returns the value and `atRow:column:put:` sets it. I used an array of arrays to hold the results.

Answer (score 1):

The question is ambiguous, because it is not strictly Seaside related but more related with the architecture of your application, in particular persistence.

A few questions...

- What `#insertOrUpdateEntryWithCode:withName:forDay:month:year:` does and return?
- How do you get access to a database connection? (global pool or your Seaside session?)

Also, you're using an old version of Pharo probably with an old version of Seaside, and if PostgreSQL connection is required, I'd avise you to use the [P3 driver](https://github.com/svenvc/P3).

Comment: That method takes the code (which is the value I enter in the cell) and then some attributes for the cell (representing some columns in the DB table: Name, Day,etc.), then inserts or updates the table using a query (security doesn't matter). I tried using `(html jQuery this)html` to return the content of the tag, but it just returns a JQuery Instance (perhaps I don't understand it very well). I get acces via Seaside session. Thank you very very much, Mr. Maringolo ! It means a lot ! I really want to finish this project because i've been searching for weeks for a solution for this simple app!

Comment: The connection to the Database works, since I made a form where I select the attributes for the cell, then I insert a value and the button performs a query that inserts my new entry, but it's just too laborious. And that entry gets inserted in the table. Also, I'll try the P3 driver.